# rewrite url ?page=2 to /page/2 with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite my url, **ONLY** for the directory `photos` ?

`http://www.abc.com/photos/index.php?page=2` to `http://www.abc.com/photos/page/2`

**My .htaccess**

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteRule ^photos/page/([0-9]+) index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: This is the correct behaviour. You shouldn't rewrite to an SEO URL. Better to rewrite to the dynamic page, since you're still able to access the `$_GET` vars... Please re-consider your downvote.

Comment: Ah ok ! I didn't see it :p

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^photos/index.php?page=([0-9]*)$ /photos/page/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: the reason for SEO redirect is that pages that have 2 access points will both be indexed - which you do not want.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which strings are dynamic, so I am assuming for this answer that `page` and `2` are variable.

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php                 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/photos/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*      photos/index.php?%1=%2          [L,QSA]
```

Maps internally

`http://www.abc.com/photos/key/val`  with or without trailing slash

To:

`http://www.abc.com/photos/index.php?key=val`

Strings `key` and `val` are assumed to be variable while `photos` is assumed to be fixed.

For permanent and visible redirection, replace `[L,QSA]` with  `[R=301,L,QSA]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^photos/page/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ photos/index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^photos/page/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ photos/index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: This will rewrite the whole site, not just the `/photos/` directory.